# Changes are not applied to all the activities

Tags: android, android-activity, taskstackbuilder, android-night-mode

I implemented night mode in my app.User can change the night mode settings in profile activity.The order of activities are as follows.

TabbedActivity>>DisplayActivity,ProfileActivity

The changed settings are applied only in current activity.(i.e profile activity).If the user presses back button,changes are not applied to that activities.Anyone help me to apply changes to all the activites.When we close the app and open again.changes are applied.But back press doesn't work.

This is the code I am using.

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    final SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
getSharedPreferences("NIGHT_MODE", MODE_PRIVATE);
    int result=sharedPreferences.getInt("NIGHT_MODE_OPTION",0);

    if (result==2){
        setTheme(R.style.darkTheme);
    }else setTheme(R.style.AppTheme);
    loadLocale();
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);
final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("NIGHT_MODE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();



    if (result==2){
        night.setChecked(true);
    }
    night.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                editor.putInt("NIGHT_MODE_OPTION",AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_YES);
                editor.apply();
                startActivity(getIntent());
            }else {
                AppCompatDelegate.setDefaultNightMode(AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                editor.putInt("NIGHT_MODE_OPTION",AppCompatDelegate.MODE_NIGHT_NO);
                editor.apply();
               startActivity(getIntent());

            }
        }
    });
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'i think the better practice would to restart/reset app  everytime the theme is changed'

```java
Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(getBaseContext().getPackageName());
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP); 
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK); 
startActivity(i); 
finish();
```

Comment: CAn you please explain the first line of the code.I did not understand.What is MyApp and A.I mean what should i write in my case.I am updating in profile activity

Comment: I applied your code.But when i press back button.Changes are not applied.If i close and open the app again,then the changes are applied

Comment: Intent i = getBaseContext().getPackageManager()
.getLaunchIntentForPackage( getBaseContext().getPackageName() );
i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
startActivity(i);
finish();                      try this

Comment: I need to write this code in which activity I am making changes?

Comment: you need to write this code in clicklistener where you are changing theme

Comment: Thank you bro.This worked.This restarted the whole app.Please edit the answer.

Comment: Is there any other way bro without restarting the whole app and apply changes to whole app.

Comment: yeah you have to use onResume() in each activity to implement changes. whish is not a good practice.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are **not** considering Android lifecycle. You configure everything inside `onCreate`. However, while switching between activities current activity's lifecycle change accordingly. [Here](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-life-cycle-of-activity) is lifecycle is explained very well

**Solution:**

When you come back to the previous activity, `onResume` is called. You should apply all changes inside this method

```
override fun onResume() {
   super.onResume()

   //Read your settings from SharedPrefs then apply, here
}
```

Comment: So,there is no need to apply changes in onCreate?

Comment: Yes exactly, Since this method is arguable always called